# what is the base font-size if the body element has already been set in rem

Tags: css

I have inherited a site and I wanted to check out what the base `font-size` was and was pretty surprised to find out that the base `font-size` was set in `rem`.

It is also set as `0.9rem`

```css
body:global {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: $main-font;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

If the base is set in 0.9 then can I assume that 0.9 is 0.9 of 16px or 14.4px?

Is there any way I can prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rem values are relative to the root html element, not to the parent element. That is, If font-size of the root element is 16px then 1 rem = 16px for all elements. If font-size is not explicitly defined in root element then 1rem will be equal to the default font-size provided by the browser (usually 16px).

And in your doubt the so in your doubt the answer is you have to assume that it will take the default font-size provided by the browser (usually 16px) of root html element.So 0.9 rem means it is 0.9 of 16px.